MediaFoundation: TimeStamp of first frame is not getting correctly set to 0. Instead, it is getting set as 0.333 (frame duration)
I'm trying to read two frames, each individually stored in binary files named frame1.bin and frame2.bin, and create an MP4 video file called sample.mp4. The complete source code is available here:
https://github.com/eswar-2001/MFWriter/blob/main/MFWriter.cpp
Here's what I'm doing:
I read a frame, associate it with its respective timestamp, and write it to the video file.
CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> mediaBuffer(createMediaBuffer(input));

// Create a media sample and add the buffer to the sample.
CComPtr<IMFSample> sample;
MFWRITER_RETURN_ON_ERROR(throwIf(MFCreateSample(&sample)));
MFWRITER_RETURN_ON_ERROR(throwIf(sample->AddBuffer(mediaBuffer)));

// Set the time stamp and the duration.
MFWRITER_RETURN_ON_ERROR(throwIf(sample->SetSampleTime(_frameStart)));
MFWRITER_RETURN_ON_ERROR(throwIf(sample->SetSampleDuration(_frameDuration)));

// Send the sample to the Sink Writer.
MFWRITER_RETURN_ON_ERROR(throwIf(_sinkWriter->WriteSample(_videoStreamIndex, sample)));

// Advance the starting position for the next frame
_frameStart += _frameDuration;

I create and set the properties of sinkWriter as below:
std::wstring wideFile = L"sample.mp4";
CComPtr<IMFMediaType> pMediaTypeOut, pMediaTypeIn;
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(wideFile.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &_sinkWriter));

// Set the output media type.
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeOut));
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video));
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264));

MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH264VProfile_Main));

// Set the Bit rate.  NOTE this assumes the input data is natively 24 bits per pixel (8 per band, 3 bands)
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, computeH264BitRate(_quality, width, height, _frameRate, 24)));

MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive));

MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, width, height));

_frameDuration = static_cast<long long>(std::round((1.0 / _frameRate) * HUNDRED_NANOSECONDS));

// Derive the frame rate from 
UINT32 rateNumerator = 0, rateDenominator = 0;
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(MFAverageTimePerFrameToFrameRate(_frameDuration, &rateNumerator, &rateDenominator));

MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, rateNumerator, rateDenominator));

MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1));
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(_sinkWriter->AddStream(pMediaTypeOut, &_videoStreamIndex));


// Set the input media type.
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeIn));
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video));
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_YUY2));

MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(pMediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive));
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, width, height));
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, rateNumerator, rateDenominator));
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1));

MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(_sinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(_videoStreamIndex, pMediaTypeIn, NULL));


_frameStart = 0;

// Tell the sink writer to start accepting data.
MFWRITER_RETURN_HRESULT_ON_ERROR(_sinkWriter->BeginWriting());

return true;

Problem: 
The timestamp is starting at 0.0333 instead of 0, which seems to correspond to the frame duration value. I printed the _frameStart value before and after associating it with the sample using SetSampleTime, and it printed 0 in both cases, as expected. However, in the generated MP4 file, the timestamp of the first frame is 0.0333 instead of 0. I am unable to determine the cause of this issue.

You could have attached files you push in and file you have created.

Sorry about that. This is my first time asking in StackOverflow. Would get better at it. Thanks

You can edit question here, and as files are needed maybe you could place those in a githuv repo. Anyway... the idea to improve the question itself, and you will get better feedback then.

Thanks alot. I wanted to attach the code some way or the other. Using GitHub never actually hit my mind. I have edited the question. Thanks for your comment

Your recording implicitly uses format converter and it apparently does not like the duration of your frames. With correct time and reduced frame this would give you the expected result.
MFWRITER_RETURN_ON_ERROR(throwIf(sample->SetSampleDuration(1))); //_frameDuration)));

I would assume that it's non-accelerated YUY2 -> NV12 converted introduces this glitch, but I am not sure (that is, it requires investigation outside of scope of this question).

That actually set the timestamp of the first frame to 0. But given that I calculate the bitRate and frameDuration from frameRate, I would be pleased to know why "it does not like the duration of your frames.". Or in other words, why is it not accepting the time duration im giving.

You feed in YUY2 frames, and this requires Video Processor MFT to jump in internally and convert the frames into NV12. This component also normalizes frame rate, meaning that it technically can drop frames and duplicate them. I would guess that by putting duration too large you make it think that this frame spans over frames #0 and #1 and so it decides to consider it as #1 skipping #0. We are unlikely to have further detail on this though, just an educated guess.

Thank you for your reply. I understand that the MFT is doing some internal transformations, and thus we are seeing this behavior. I would love to read through the doc explaining this. I was able to find the following doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/time-stamps-and-durations. But this not explaining the behavior.
Anyways thankyou for your response, I'm atleast able to get what might be actually happening in the background.

Such details are now better documented here than on MSDN :) I don't think you would find any reference better than described here. This should mostly be behavior of VideoProcessor MFT, but this is still a guess as one has to see the detail in order to provide a statement.

I completely agree.
